# The meaning of "but I told you so"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> If I Сould Tell You. W.H. Auden (1907– 1973)
>
> Time will say nothing but I told you so,
>
> Time only knows the price we have to pay;
>
> If I could tell you I would let you know.

I'd like to know the meaning of "but I told you so".My interpretation is "I warned you it would be like that " but other people see it like "but I explained everything to you instead of Time".

How to tell the meaning from the grammatical structure or vocabulary of this sentence?

Comment: I think the confusion comes from your separating *but* from *nothing*. *Nothing but* means only as *but* means *except (for)*. A comma will make a huge difference in this kind of sentence, but it is not easy to tell what it really means.

Comment: Also, BTW, we normally put "Only" at the beginning of the sentence "Only Bob has the key to this door."   when we want to say "No one else has a key."  "Bob only has the key to this door." would normally mean "Bob does not have the key to that other door." However, there is a common saying "God only knows..." and there it means "Only God knows". So that the line that begins "Time only knows" could be taken to mean "Only Time knows" rather than "the only thing Time knows is the price we have to pay". Hence, the final line.

Comment: Time is Auden 's favourite topic and the most important factor in his philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line in your cited poem

> **Time will say nothing but I told you so,**
>   Time will say nothing *except* I told you so,

WH Auden is saying that the **passing of time is silent** but through that passing we will always know the **results of our actions**.

> **I told you so**

is a well known phrase used to tell someone **after the consequences** who was

> **forewarned but did not listen**
>
> This morning, I said to bring an umbrella, **I told you so**
>   If you dried your hair you wouldn't have caught a cold, **I told you so**
>
> P1: I don't understand what went wrong.
>   P2: ***But*** **I told you so** yesterday.

It **not a nice thing to say** to someone and is a form of [**gloating**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=gloating+meaning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=j6S9VrvKD7LS8AeUp5jYBg).

Auden is making a reference to another saying

> **Time will tell all**

Auden is poetically saying that **time will let us know** if we made the correct decisions or not.

If the same **I told you so** happens many times, one can use

> **How many times do I have to tell you!**

to stress the point

Comment: Does it mean I got it correctly (warned )?

Comment: What's "so" here?

Comment: I told you *(it would be)* **so**. "I warned you it would be like that" is correct

Answer (score 1):

> Time will say nothing but I told you so,

Let me rephrase the above sentence to an easier version. It could be interpreted in two ways:

1. With [hindsight 20/20](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hindsight_is_20/20) which means

> (idiomatic) In hindsight things are **obvious** that were not obvious from
>   the outset; one is able to evaluate past choices more clearly than at
>   the time of the choice.

time will prove that what I (**not time**) told (warn) you was the right thing to say.

2. Time will say **only** time (**not I**) is (could be) right. In other words, time is the only thing that can say whether the decision you made in the past was right or wrong. You could never know what would happen in the future. Only time will be able to tell it. The author expressed the same thing using the following sentence.

> Time only knows the price we have to pay;

It means there is nothing other than **time** that can surely know whether anything was right or wrong. I think **I** in the first sentence means **time** and the second interpretation looks more convincing to me after reading the second and third sentences.

> If I could tell you I would let you know.

This sentence means "Since I am neither **time** nor **prophet**, I can't let you know what will happen in the future.

Note: It is a poem which is not easy to interpret. I write this answer using my primarily-opinion-based interpretation.